# Django: Is there a way to keep the dev server from restarting when a local .py file is changed and dynamically loaded?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

In Django (1.9) trying to load `.py` files (modules) dynamically (via `importlib`). The dynamic reload is working like a charm, but every time I reload a module, the dev server restarts, having to reload everything else.

I'm pulling in a lot of outside data (xml) for testing purposes, and every time the environment restarts, it has to reload all of this external xml data. I want to be able to reload a module only, and keep that already loaded xml data intact, so that it doesn't have to go through that process every time I change some py-code.

**Is there a flag I can set/toggle (or any other method) to keep the server from restarting the whole process for this single module reload?**

Any help very appreciated.

Answer (score 86, accepted):

If you run the development server using [`--noreload`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/django-admin/#cmdoption-runserver-noreload) parameter it will not auto reload the changes:

```
python manage.py runserver --noreload
```

> Disables the auto-reloader. This means any Python code changes you make while the server is running will not take effect if the particular Python modules have already been loaded into memory.